# Are memory updates local in mammals?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, memory

What I mean is, during long term potentiation (LTP) or long term depression (LTD) for a particular memory, do the strengthening and/or weakening of neuronal connections only occur in a small patch of neurons or regions spread out in the cortex?

Comment: LTD and LTP happen at individual synapses (not even whole of neurons). However LTP/LTD at one synapse can affect others in the vicinity.

Comment: OK I meant something like when a single episodic memory episode is stored, is the memory stored in diffuse locations or rather localized?

Answer (score 1):

LTP and LTD are processes that operate on single synapses. We don't know how "memories" (there are several types of "memory") are encoded in the human nervous system. As a consequence, we don't yet understand the explicit link between some group of synaptically connected neurons, and a given memory.

So the short answer is "we don't know". Take a look at some of the other questions about memories in human brains: [1](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/775/how-and-where-in-the-human-brain-are-memories-stored?rq=1), [2](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1198/long-term-potentiation-and-memory-where-do-we-stand?rq=1)